# Android Large Table Inside ScrollView Very Slow to Build

Tags: android, performance

I am building a dynamic table layout with 1,000 rows. The build is fairly quick, but drawing it takes over 10 seconds. The table contains three image buttons and 7 text columns. Once loaded the table performs quite well, but reloading it (i.e. when changing the sort order) is also very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am building a dynamic table layout with 1,000 rows

That is an exceedingly bad idea. For starters, you will crash with an `OutOfMemoryError` on some devices, as you are blowing through several MB of heap space in just one activity.

Please use a `ListView`, or some other form of `AdapterView`, so that only as many views as is needed to fill the screen are created (and then recycled as the user scrolls).